# Laravel 4 routing css

Tags: css, exception, routes, laravel

I am trying to link to my css document in laravel 4

my css is located at

```
public/css/style.css
```

inside my view my link is

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::asset('css/style.css')}}" />
```

This produces what i would believe to be the correct page as it looks like the correct link in the view sources

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/css/style.css" />
```

but when i click on the link i get the error that the page doesn't exist
the title of the pages is **whoops there was an error**

it says that the page doesn't exist.

I saw this problem before if i didn't create a route in the route.php for some other files
do i need to create a route for all of my css/javascript/images files?

There must be an easier what to route things. like with a regex of some type somewhere?

i believe that it's somehow routing to this index.php file

**virtual host configured which is why the directory is different from htdocs**

C:/Sites/localhost/public/index.php

the script filename was index.php
but the redirect URI name was /css/styling.css

still i get the exception...

If you need some more info please let me know. I believe this is all that is needed to understand tho. Let me know if i am wrong

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that your `.htaccess` file is not allowing for the exclusion of files that exist on your server.

So, if you don't see `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` above the rule that sends everything to `index.php`, then you know what the culprit is.

If it is there, please post the content of that file, as well as a list of your routes in `routes.php` in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
{{ HTML::style('css/style.css') }}
```

Comment: i think it's the route.php file? do i have to create a route for my css file?